# Error using WordPress $wpdb object to get result from custom table

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to use $wpdb object to get results from a custom table and I get an error when I echo the result:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$category in...
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
global $wpdb;
$prodCat = $wpdb->get_results( 
"SELECT * FROM product_category" , OBJECT_K);
    foreach ( $prodCat as $row ){
                echo $row->category-name;
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. the problem was because of my column name 'category-name, I changed it to categoryName in database and worked fine. It had something to do with the hyphen ' - '.